# which is better between the two kinds of css reset?

Tags: css, css-reset

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

and

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,
form,fieldset,legend,input,button,textarea,blockquote,th,td,p...{
    margin:0;padding:0
}
```

the first is simple,and I like it.But why many big web sites use the second method

Comment: May be they need of the margin and padding of the Some HTML elements

Comment: not a big difference, I think. but some elements do not have margin and padding like divs and spans.. so go with the second approach. this is completely my opinion.

Comment: This [link](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/universal-selector-css-reset/) might help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [universal selector (`*`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) selects *all* elements on a page. This is great, but this selector would end up unnecessarily targeting elements which shouldn't realistically have no margin or padding by default.

Targeting specific elements is more logical as you wouldn't then have to override this CSS later on. For instance, if you wanted all instances of `li` elements within your document to have both margin and padding, you wouldn't want to include it within your list of selectors; equally you wouldn't want this to be targeted with `*` as it would add (albeit a very minuscule amount) to the time it takes for your page to render.

Nowadays a lot of websites actually make use of [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) ([direct link to stylesheet](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css)) to reset CSS:

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards.

Answer (score 0):

The first one does not clutter your debug tool (like Firebug) but the second one is more customizable as you can choose the elements that are not reset. Usually [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) files do not reset element like `input`, `select` or `button` and use the second form.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SECOND ONE

because this is 
               Best one 
               logically correct 
               sometimes we need to use default properties of HTML elements.